# What are the exact applications of cover-letter and application-letter tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two tags with the following excerpts:

[cover-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cover-letter)

> For questions about cover letter attached to applications or curricula
>   vitae. This is not for cover letters for submissions to journals.

[application-letter](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application-letter)

> Discussing content and approach for formal letters of application, to
>   be written by the candidate (not letters of reference).

Which I think have similar excerpts and user may be confused by their applications.

What are the differences between those two tags and in which questions should they be correctly used?

Also, it seems that we do not have a tag about the cover letters which should be written in order to submit a manuscript to a journal or conference and we have many questions about this on website.

Here are my suggestions:

1. We should edit the the tag excerpts above and make them more precise.
2. We may need a new tag to cover questions about paper's cover letters. (But I think that we do not need a new tag for paper's cover letters because we can edit the existing tags.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Could you please take a look at this question?

Comment: These are pretty much identical, and should probably be merged, with the latter as a synonym for the former.

Comment: @aeismail Also I think that the cover-letter tag's excerpt should be edited to include all kinds of cover letters; such as the ones written for admissions purposes, applications letters, and letters for paper submission.

Comment: But that last type is vastly different from the others (and also seems to be outdated in most cases).

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: I agree with Tobias. A journal submission cover letter is _completely_ different from the others. I don't think it needs its own tag, though: it's adequately covered by [tag:paper-submission].

Comment: Actually, many of the questions currently tagged [tag:application-letter] are tagged incorrectly (the questions are actually about [tag:recommendation-letter], [tag:statement-of-purpose], or just general [tag:application]). These should be corrected (slowly); then a moderator can merge application-letter into cover-letter.

Comment: I think that most of the questions tagged with [tag:application-letter] can be covered by either [tag:cover-letter], [tag:graduate-admissions] or [tag:application] tags.

Comment: @ff524 [tag:application-letter] tag has now no attached question.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent: @-pinging only works for people involved in the respective post, so I only noticed this now. Anyway, I have little to add to the existing remarks and am not sufficiently experienced with applications to answer on this aspect.